# How to add new column to asp.net gridview where columns are autogenerated?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to add new hyperlink column to an asp.net gridview where columns are autogenerated? The columns are not predefined in the gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add your column definition the  section of the gridview.  Your auto-generated columns should show up to the left of this one.

```
<asp:gridview AutoGenerateColumns="true" ... >
    <columns>
        <asp:hyperlink ... />
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be the HyperLinkField not the regular hyperlink controlwhich gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

I find that autogenerated columns appear to the RIGHT.  If you want them to be on the left, you have to add code to the RowCreated event which deletes and re-adds all columns, like so:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();

        foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        {
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
            row.Cells.Remove(cell);
            columns.Add(cell);
        }

        row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
    }
```

Found article here:  [http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/03/move--autogenerate-columns-at-leftmost-part-of-the-gridview.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200621194226/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/03/move--autogenerate-columns-at-leftmost-part-of-the-gridview.aspx)